# Match values to specific field of rows in Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

Consider two dataframes:
df 1:

```
ID    value1    value2    result
1     50        -50       1111
2     20        -20       2222
3     -75.50    25        3333
```

df 2:

```
ID    value3    value4    result
101   20        -20       
201   -75.50    25        
756   50        -50
```

How can I match the results to the right columns with Python?

Answer is :

```
ID    value3    value4    result
101   20        -20       2222
201   -75.50    25        3333
756   50        -50       1111
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into merges
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
pd.merge( df1, df2,
          left_on = ["value1","value2"],
          right_on = ["value3","value4"] )
```